# Converting lat-lon from degrees and decimal minutes to decimal degrees in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, convert, latitude-longitude, decimal-points

Creating a geometry in Postgis is fairly simple:

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude),4326);
```

These lat/lon should be in decimal degrees format like `33.02505 -96.70668`

Is there a way/function to enter them in the degrees and decimal minutes format provided by NMEA $GPRMC sentences like `3301.5032 09642.4010`?

Of course you can convert them in php or nodejs; but it would be easier (faster) to have it natively in Postgis.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a user contributed PostGIS function called dms2dd. Your data however looks like Degree, decimal Minutes. You may need to modify the function to suite your needs. [functions](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiplpgsqlfunctions)